# Include multiple choices in 'LIKE'

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to display all vendors where the first address is a PO Box but I am struggling how to format that using LIKE. In my table the PO Box can be formatted any of those 3 ways but I am not sure how to include all 3 in the LIKE. What I currently have here fives me a "missing right parenthesis" error

```
SELECT vendor_name, vendor_address1, vendor_address2
FROM ap_vendors
WHERE vendor_address1 LIKE ('PO Box%', 'P. O. Box%', 'P O Box%')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
WHERE regexp_like(vendor_address1, '^(PO Box|P. O. Box|P O Box)')
```

Or multiple `LIKE` patterns:

```
WHERE vendor_address1 LIKE 'PO Box%' OR
      vendor_address1 LIKE 'P. O. Box%' OR
      vendor_address1 LIKE 'P O Box%'
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that what you want is OR logic

You can do this like so:

```
SELECT vendor_name, vendor_address1, vendor_address2
FROM ap_vendors
WHERE vendor_address1 LIKE 'PO Box%' 
  OR vendor_address1 LIKE 'P. O. Box%'
  OR vendor_address1 LIKE 'P O Box%'
```